# Looping in a list of 25 authors that have missing citations in google scholar

Tags: python

I am using `from scholarly import scholarly` to obtain the counts of citations of a list of 25 professors in the professor list from Google scholar. However some authors do not have citations. How am I able to loop and stop the iteration. I have tried with the code below:

```
for i in professorlist:
    if i in professorlist:
        a = scholarly.search_author(i)
author = next(search_query)
scholarly.pprint(scholarly.fill(author, sections=['counts']))
if i not in professorlist:
    print ("no citations")
```

But I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-636-b3aa9d644e9f> in <module>
      2     if i in professorlist:
      3         a = scholarly.search_author(i)
----> 4 author = next(search_query)
      5 scholarly.pprint(scholarly.fill(author, sections=['counts']))
      6 if i not in professorlist:

StopIteration:
```

Comment: You need to wrap your `author = next(search_query)` inside a try/except StopIteration block

Comment: What is `search_query`? And why are you checking if `i` is in `professorlist`? You are literally iterating `professorlist` so of course it's there...

Comment: Thanks, any idea how i do that @crissal? I'm am only just starting out with python.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a generator, you can obtain items calling `next` method, like you did in the snippet provided; however, if you call this method on an exhausted/empty generator, you get a StopIteration error.

You can manage this by wrapping it into a try/except block like this.

```py
try:
    author = next(search_query)
except StopIteration:
    print("Iterated over all authors")
else:
    # do something with your author
    pass
```

You can also iterate over a generator with a `for` loop; it will take care automatically of the StopIteration error, exiting when the generator is exhausted.

```py
for author in search_query:
    # do something with your author
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you :)
Do you mean like this?

for author in search_query:
    scholarly.pprint(scholarly.fill(author, sections=['counts']))
    pass

it seems to work but does not return any results

Answer (score 0):

for author in search_query:
scholarly.pprint(scholarly.fill(author, sections=['counts']))
pass

Thank you :) Do you mean like this @

it seems to go through but does not return any results